# Rails: can I pass multiple values into the include method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

So

```
shout = "gabba gabba hey"
```

of course does

```
shout.include?("gabba")
=> true

shout.include?("nothing")
=> false
```

Also this works

```
shout.include?("gabba"||"nothing")
=> true
```

However this doesn't

```
shout.include?("nothing"||"gabba")
=> false
```

I'm confused. Doesn't this operator work in an include at all, does it stop after evaluating the first value no matter if it returns true or false, or am I just missing something essential? Of course I could use this far longer code

```
shout.include?("nothing") or shout.include?("gabba")
=> true
```

but I'd rather have it short and concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use regexp instead:

```
!! (shout =~ /(gabba|nothing)/)
```

`/(gabba|nothing)/` is a regular expression matching 'gabba' or 'nothing'

`=~` returns the position of the regular expression in your string, if found

`!!` makes sure the result of the operation is `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't.

What you tried:

```
shout.include?('gabba' || 'nothing')
```

is equivalent to

```
shout.include?('gabba')
```

because

```
'gabba' || 'nothing'
# => 'gabba'
```

and this is how `||` operator works in Ruby. It returns first operand unless it's `false` or `nil`. Otherwise, it returns second operand. Since your first operand is `'gabba'` string, it's being returned.